# SQLite: treat non-existent column as NULL

Tags: sqlite, database-migration

I have a query like this (simplified and anonymised):

```
SELECT
    Department.id,
    Department.name,
    Department.manager_id,
    Employee.name AS manager_name
FROM
    Department
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee
    ON Department.manager_id = Employee.id;
```

The field `Department.manager_id` may be `NULL`. If it is non-`NULL` then it is guaranteed to be a valid `id` for precisely one row in the `Employee` table, so the `OUTER JOIN` is there just for the rows in the `Department` table where it is `NULL`.

Here is the problem: old instances of the database do not have this `Department.manager_id` column at all. In those cases, I would like the query to act as if the  field did exist but was always `NULL`, so e.g. the `manager_name` field is returned as `NULL`. If the query only used the `Department` table then I could just use `SELECT *` and check for the column in my application, but the `JOIN` seems to make this impossible. I would prefer not to modify the database, partly so that I can load the database in read only mode. Can this be done just by clever adjustment of the query?

Comment: If the a column that is referenced in the query does not exist, your query will error - as far as I see, there is no way to avoid that.

Comment: @GMB Obviously the query I've written will certainly not work. But I thought there could be done trick that I'm not enough of an expert to think of. For example, instead of using `Department` directly, use a nested query that contains another nested query that also has a `manager_id` field, but in such a way that the one in `Department` takes precedence if it exists.

Comment: What are these "old instances of the database", and how and why are you also trying to access them?  I.e. why don't you convert them to the new schema?

Comment: @Greg Since this is SQLite, these database instances are just files on disk

Comment: And so?  Why not update them to have the new schema?

Comment: @Greg This is a GUI process that ideally shouldn't be mucking around with these files. (There's another process that creates and updates the database, which you could maybe call the server process, but that's not quite right side it all runs on the user's machine.) What's more, adding a column which I know will only ever have `NULL` values in it seems pointless if I could structure the query to avoid it. I will consider it as a last resort though.

Comment: Well if they're all supposed to ostensibly be the same schema, then make them the same schema exactly.  I don't think you'll be able to fool the query parser into ignoring a sometimes nonexistent column in a table, at least not with SQLite, and even if you could it still feels rather wrong to do so.  Adding a column isn't pointless if it makes your queries work properly.

Comment: If you were not short-cutting the DB migration process by copying low-level files (e.g. because you couldn't), then you would probably have built a (possibly continuous) migration process that would be able to deal with different versions of the "remote" schema as it copies the data into a unified central database.

Comment: @GregA.Woods I think you are not familiar with SQLite. It is used for applications where a local file is strictly required and using SQL as an interface is more like a bonus feature. There are hundreds, or more, SQLite files on whatever device you are currently using. Would you be happy if you could not save a word processing document or spreadsheet as a file, only to someone's "unfied central database"? (Sadly that is how the world is going.) From the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html): "SQLite does not compete with client/server databases. SQLite competes with fopen(). "

Comment: Admittedly, schema migration is a perfectly normal thing for SQLite databases, especially backwards-compatible changes like this one. But so is opening a file read only if you do not plan to modify its content (e.g. it would be annoying if you opened an old Word document and it said "before we open this document we'll need to migrate it to a new format...").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT
    Dept.id,
    Dept.name,
    Dept.manager_id,
    Employee.name AS manager_name
FROM
    (SELECT *, NULL AS manager_id FROM Department) AS Dept
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee
    ON Dept.manager_id = Employee.id;
```

If the `manager_id` column is present in `Department` then it is used for the join, whereas if it is not then `Dept.manager_id` and `Employee.name` are both NULL.

If I swap the column order in the subquery:

```
(SELECT NULL AS manager_id, * FROM Department) AS Dept
```

then the `Dept.manager_id` and `Employee.name` are both NULL even if the `Department.manager_id` column exists, so it seems that `Dept.manager_id` refers to the *first* column in the `Dept` subquery that has that name. It would be good to find a reference in the SQLite documentation saying that this behaviour is guaranteed (or explicitly saying that it is not), but I can't find anything (e.g. in the [`SELECT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) or [expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) pages).

I haven't tried this with other database systems so I don't know if it will work with anything other than SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is an answer that does not require munging both possible schemas into one query (but still doesn't need you to actually do the schema migration):

Check for the schema version, and use that to determine which `SELECT` query to issue (i.e. with or without the `manager_id` column and `JOIN`) as a separate step. Here are a few possibilities to determine the schema version:

- The ideal situation is that you already keep track of the schema by assigning version numbers to the schema and recording them in the database. Commonly this is done with either:

  - The [`user_version` pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version).
  - A table called "Schema" or similar with one row containing the schema version number.
- You can directly determine whether the column is present in the table. Two possibilities:

  - Use the [`table_info` pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) to determine the list of columns in the table.
  - Use a simple `SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 1` and look at what columns are returned (this is probably better as it is independent of the database engine).